# How to make this CarouFredSel slider responsive?

Tags: javascript, slider, carousel, caroufredsel

This example implementation of a CarouFredSel slider is said to be responsive, when in fact it is not:

[Responsive carousel showing one image and two images partially](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/68/)

I tried to get it responsive by adding `responsive: true`, but this did not work:

- [JSFiddle: Code](http://jsfiddle.net/bytesource/fC5kx/18/)
- [JSFiddle: Result](http://jsfiddle.net/bytesource/fC5kx/18/embedded/result/)

I would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction. Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Why would "responsive:true" work if there's no code to handle that option? The carousel is not responsive on the demo page...

Comment: You're assigning the `item` attribute twice, too.